# &nbsp removal in PHP

Tags: php

I need to remove all dodgy html characters from a web-site I'm parsing using Curl and simplehtml dom.

```
<?php
$html = "this is&nbsp;a text";
var_dump($html);
var_dump(html_entity_decode($html,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8"));
```

Which outputs

> string(19) "this is a text"
>
> string(15) "this is┬áa text"

I don't want to use preg* as there are other characters in the text (e.g. &deg).
This is driving me insane now!

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify your output encoding with a header:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $html = "this is&nbsp;a text";
    var_dump($html);
    var_dump(html_entity_decode($html,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8"));
?>
```

The browser does not assume UTF-8 by default, that's why it displays the wrong character.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick reply. This only changed the corrupt character. I'm running on a command line in windows, would that make a difference? The output was "string(19) "this is&nbsp;a text"
string(15) "this is┬áa text""

Comment: Also changed both to ISO-8859-1 but now just a different character.

Comment: The header will only fix it in your browser, I don't know about the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only character that needs replacing just use `str_replace()`

```
var_dump(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', "this is&nbsp;a text"));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iyGMGl)

Comment: He said "I need to remove all dodgy html characters", not just &nbsp;. Interesting immediate upvotes.

Comment: Reluctantly had to go with this approach, but not happy about it, as it means if any HTML character I've not considered pops up, my solution breaks. I'm leaving the question as unanswered though. A side solution I've considered is #&[a-zA-Z];# as in normal english there would always be a space around the & symbol.